# CSS to PDF,the css in Flying Saucer : -fs-table-paginate result in border-collapse:collapse invalid

Tags: html, css, flying-saucer, xhtmlrenderer

Now I am using **xhtmlrenderer** to covert html to PDF.
My maven dependancy as follows:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mvel</groupId>
        <artifactId>mvel2</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.drools2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
        <artifactId>core-renderer</artifactId>
        <version>R8</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.8</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
```

I am trying to repeat the table head in every PDF's page.So I use the css:

```
table {
        -fs-table-paginate: paginate;
    }`
```

The explain for the CSS is [here](http://flyingsaucerproject.github.com/flyingsaucer/r8/guide/users-guide-R8.html#xil_43).

```
-fs-table-paginate
```

- when used with the value `-fs-table-paginate: paginate`, modifies the table layout algorithm to repeat table headers and footers on subsequent pages and improve the appearance of cells that break across pages (for example by closing and reopening borders), but that's all it does. If a table's minimum width is wider than the page, it will be chopped off.
- When add the above css my table's borders are detached.

[image]

- Before I add the css , the table's borders are collapsed into single border.

[image]

So I think the `table { -fs-table-paginate: paginate; }` made my table `border-collapse:collapse` invalid.

**So what can I do to fix the bug, make the table's borders collapse?**

My app CSS for the table as follows

```
table{
    border:1px solid #000000;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    -fs-table-paginate: paginate;
}
table td{
    border:1px solid #000000;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    white-space:normal;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-align:left;
    line-height:16px;
    height:16px;

}
table tr{
    page-break-inside:avoid;
}
table thead tr th{
    background:#f2f2f2;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    text-align:center;
}

table tr th{
    background:#f2f2f2;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    text-align:center;
}
```

And when add `-fs-table-paginate: paginate;`  sometimes the table header will be not normal. The header will **not be display correctly**. And below  table header will increase a **extra blank line**. As follows:
[image]

Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 17):

For the same problem, I used this workaround:

```
table {
  -fs-table-paginate: paginate;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
```

It worked for me, my `thead` is repeated on each page.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning border-spacing, that helped

Comment: That helped! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes... you are correct...

border-collapse: collapse and -fs-table-paginate: paginate cannot be used
together. border-collapse is reset to separate when -fs-table-paginate is set to
paginate...

So the better way to implement your table header is by using thead... [this may help u](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#edef-THEAD)...

Comment: I have already use the thead.Also cann't be repeated the table head in every PDF's page

Answer (score 1):

Workaround that worked for me :

Init all `th` and `td` one by one with border set to 0px : `border: 0px;`

And then apply border where you need them like this :

`<td style="border: 0px; border-left: 1px solid #ddd;">some texte</td>`

Of course I let `-fs-table-paginate: paginate;` in table style.

Working sample html : https://gist.github.com/laguiz/5509461

Here is the result :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can set border left width and border top width 0, just use this css

```
    table {
        -fs-table-paginate:paginate;
    }

    table * {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-color: #000;
    }

    table thead tr:first-child th {
        border-top-width: 1px;
        border-top-style: solid;
    }

    table tr th:first-child,
    table tr td:first-child {
        border-left-width: 1px;
        border-left-style: solid;
    }

    table tr th,
    table tr td {
        border-top-width: 0px;
        border-right-width: 1px;
        border-bottom-width: 1px;
        border-left-width: 0px;
        border-bottom-style: solid;
        border-right-style: solid;
    }
```